# Evaluating previous checkpoints

Tags: tensorboard

I'm fairly new to TensorFlow, and is experimenting with Bert in TensorFlow. I notice that the example scripts are storing checkpoints every 1000 epoch. It is both storing .data, .index and .meta for each checkpoints. It also creates an eval-folder with a events.out.tfevents.*-file.

It stores an eval_results.txt-file containing the evaluation results for the latest checkpoints.

I want look at the eval-results for previous checkpoints both to see progress and to see if I am overfitting.

I had some issues getting tensorboard running. Are these kind of data stored in the .meta or .index? Do I need tensorboard to see this data, or are there other ways? Or do I have to rerun predictions manually by loading each individual checkpoint?

Comment: New to tensorflow and directly experimenting with Bert, quite brave, the data stored in .meta or .index is viewed by tensorboard and since using it is easy I don't think any other tool exists for this, I haven't heard of one yet and it's been an year using TF, I don't think one exists, I would advice you to solve why tensorboard doesn't work, You might find an alternative, but I don't think there is one, so again you will have better luck fixing tensorboard.

Comment: Thanks. Focusing on getting the Tensorboard issue fixed was a good advice. Turned out to be just a port-forwarding/firewall issue. Unfortunately not much useful data in the meta-files though, but Ill keep digging...;) Thanks.

Comment: What seems to be the issue, what data are you looking for, also which OS are you working on, I might be able to help.

Comment: Actually, you can use tensorboards in this case. However, you can get a view of Training loss change over every step, and validation loss at the end of all the training steps. One way to break this problem is to run multiple single epoch trials, where each epoch uses the previous best results, thus you have eval loss at the end of every epoch.